# Closing a MessageBox but keeping Form Open

Tags: c#, forms, messagebox

I've made a form that a user logs in with a username and password. If the password is incorrect I have a messageBox RetryCancel. I want a user to click Retry and have the message box close while keeping the Login form still up, so the user can try to login again.

I've tried a lot of different options, basically all I get is a infinite loop or the all of the windows close. Here is what I got so far. Thanks,

```
if (line != PassWord)
do
{
        result = MessageBox.Show(message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        result = DialogResult.Retry;
        this.Close();
} while(result == DialogResult.Retry);
if (line == PassWord)
{
    Close();
}
```

Comment: You could also mimic online login forms (since people are used to those), and have a red label display above your username/password indicating the credentials are incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (line != PassWord)
{
    var result = MessageBox.Show(message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel,    MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    if (result == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
    {
        // User chose cancel, close app or whatever
    }
    else
    {
        // User pressed retry, nothing really happens
    }
}       
else if (line == PassWord)
{
    Close();
}
```

Comment: The only problem is that I want the user to enter their password again. When I click Retry the message box closes and so does the form. I want the form to stay open so they can try again.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you design a simple login form and check the login username and password on the login button. If authentication fails then simply display the message box saying "Check username and password" with okonly option.